# Remove background from empty div when content is added

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a div that starts empty but items get added to it via jQuery Sortable. What I'm hoping to do is start by showing the empty div with a border and background image, the image would say something like, "Drag items here." but as soon as the first item is moved into the empty div, the background would become blank.

I'm looking to do this as the items within the new div be reordered and I don't want the background visible while the user moves items around.

Comment: listen for the start event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of jQuery, use pure css :

```
.yourDiv:empty{
    background-image : url(...);
    //set your width / height if it isnt set in an other rule.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divChange = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('div').html().length) {
            contChanged($(this));
        }
    },100);
    function contChanged(elem) {
        $('div').css('background', '#ccc');
        clearInterval(divChange);
    }

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').html('Content added!');
    });
});
```

## [Working demo here!](http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/jpWuK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 :psuedo class :empty will work for pretty much all browsers. If you are looking to support older versions of IE (IE8 and below) I suggest using the receive function of the Sortable widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/sortable/#event-receive